# UWP Application live tile text size

Tags: .net, uwp, live-tile

There is an [Clock tile app](https://www.microsoft.com/ru-ru/store/p/start-screen-clock/9wzdncrfj0vm) in windows store. I wonder how to make the tile font size like in this app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In adaptive tiles, we should use **`hint-style`** in `text` element to set text's font size. Styles control the font size, color, and weight of text elements. However there are only a number of available styles that can be used in `hint-style`.
[image]
For more information, please see [**Text styles**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/tiles-and-notifications-create-adaptive-tiles#text-styles) in [Create adaptive tiles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/tiles-and-notifications-create-adaptive-tiles).

So we can't assign an arbitrary font size in adaptive tiles. I'd suppose in the app you've mentioned, it is sending tiles with images. The image might be generated from a custom XAML layout by implementing a [**XamlRenderingBackgroundTask**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/dn633914).

**XamlRenderingBackgroundTask** provides the ability to render XAML trees as a bitmap from a background task, often to generate custom tiles. If adaptive can’t achieve what you want on a tile, this is an option. And while using custom XAML layout, we can then set the font size with [TextBlock.FontSize](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.textblock.fontsize.aspx) property to whatever value we want.

For an example, please see [Updating a tile from a background task](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Updating-a-tile-from-a-e0e492df).